# Android Multi-Threading, Main thread is not accesable from Asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

This question maybe has asked before, but I could not find about it through my searches.

I implemented an activity in my android application and also I used an Asynctask class in this activity. I tried to make some changes on my layout from Asynctask (doInBackgroung), for this reason I called runOnUiThread from mentioned Asynctask. This works properly, but as soon as I move to another activity and return to this activity again, changes on layout not happens anymore.

It is worth to mentione that I called `asynctask.cancel(true)` when moving to the next activity and rebuild that asynctask when move back to that activity that contains mentioned Asynctask.

Please Guide me how to handle this issue.

Comment: Are you calling `.execute()` when you return to the original task? https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle This link will help you understand when you should re instantiate objects such as `AsyncTasks`

Comment: When you call setContentView() on the activity it will reload the layout defined in the xml ignoring your changes to the UI, is that your problem?

Comment: I call `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, param);` on initial of activity, in `onCreate()`. I tried `.execute` to, but it was not successful.

Comment: @Nanoc no, this is not exactly my problem. When returning to the activity, codes in my runOnUIthread that placed in asynTask(doInbackground) not works properly. These codes should change some icons in my main layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say without looking at your code but I suggest you don't call `runOnUiThread()` inside your asyncTask. Instead, create an interface inside the AsyncTask class and pass in your activity that implements the interface when constructing the AsyncTask class. Then inside `onPostExecute()` check if your listener (i.e. activity that implements your interface) is not null and call a method on that interface - this will be then handled inside the implemented method inside the activity, on the correct thread, where you can also check if you still have the right UI elements or find them by id if needed.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnAsyncFinishedListener {

    <... activity stuff ...>

    @Override
    public void onAsyncFinished() {
      // do stuff with your activity ui
    }
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private OnAsyncFinishedListener mListener; 

    public static interface OnAsyncFinishedListener {
        void onAsyncFinished();
    }

    public MyAsyncTask(OnAsyncFinishedListener listener) {
      mListener = listener
    }

    <... async task stuff ...>

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onAsyncFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I exactly did not understand my problems logic. I try to call a listener in my doInBackground part of Asynctask, and for this reason this Asynctask do not finished until the end of the activity. Each time the listener catches what expected, changes some icons on UI thread, and after that again start to listen for an event. I must call runOnUIthread in my doInBackground  method, in order to manage UIthread.

Comment: Again, I don't think you should call runOnUi inside doInBackground. That doesn't make any sense. I suggest you look into how you are designing your app. AsyncTasks should be used to do a finite job on a background thread and return the result to the main thread. If you need to do constant work on the background and update the UI with results, I suggest you use a bound Service and follow the same interface pattern as described above.